# How can I color checked label in css?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to color those labels under `<div class="navigation">` as black whenever is active on the image. I've tried writing `#r1:checked~.navigation label:nth-child(1){ background: #000; }` in CSS but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated, I am new to web development.

Thank you~

```css
.slidershow {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 10px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
}

.navigation {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  right: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .4s;
}

input[name="r"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: .6s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar:hover {
  background: #E3DFFF;
}

.bar:active {
  background: #000;

}

#r1:checked~.s1 {
  margin: 0%;
}

#r2:checked~.s1 {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#r3:checked~.s1 {
  margin-left: -40%;
}
```

```html
<!-- ##Slider## -->
<div class="slidershow middle">

  <div class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">

    <div class="slide s1">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/00bf16&text=First+Image" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/00bf16&text=Second+Image" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/00bf16&text=Third+Image" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="navigation">
  <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
  <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
  <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<input>` elements need to be **a sibling of an ancestor** of the `<label>` elements. CSS does not support "cousin" selectors - nor does it support "parent-of" selectors (this is by-design as CSS does not allow for subsequent elements to affect prior elements' selectors)

Comment: For slider, it is possible to do it without JS. But not simple. Will be better to use and _understand_ a sample slider

Comment: I agree with @SeeoX. You should go for JS or even better, go for **Jquery**. A simple CDN 
 link and you are good to go. And you can use `event handling` for this. Shouldn' take long. It will also help you further in web development. Cheers!

Comment: @JustCurious that’s bad advice: People should not be using jQuery in new projects anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by `anymore` and why? Please elaborate @Dai. Thanks.